# User changing after login

Tags: login, user-management

On Ubuntu 18.04 I think webmin screwed up my system.
When I login with ssh on my server with my own credentials, the system change my user to www-data.
Obviously this account is heavily restricted.

### Here is what happens @ login:

```
login as: jwbosch
jwbosch@jwbosch.nl's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

No mail.
Last login: Thu Jan 10 12:35:44 2019 from 192.168.111.35
www-data@webserver:~$
```

---

Now the question:
Since I can't `sudo`, how do I change the user settings for jwbosch back to normal.
jwbosch is in the sudoers list, but www-data not.

thank you for your time to help me out

Comment: What if you try to perform a su to your user, It will redirect again to www-data? [su - jwbosch]

Comment: Yes, still the samewww-data@webserver:~$ su jwbosch
Password:
www-data@webserver:~

Comment: Is it possible this is due to ssh login and it won't do it local?

Comment: No I do not think so because su - username it is a local login not use ssh, I think is related on the configuration in the user, did you have root access or at least physical access to the machine?

Comment: Root access no, physical access yes.

Comment: good, then if grub is not password protected (or you have the password) you can have the root access in the computer, please follow this instruction to get root access: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reset-lost-root-password-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Can you include `/etc/passwd` in your question? Apart from personal names, this file does not contain private information.

Comment: What is the value of the variable PS1 ? Run `echo $PS1`. Also the output of `whoami` and `id` would beinteresting to see.

Comment: Thanks for the help AtomiX84. After resetting the root password i changed uid of jwbosch back to 1000. This was changed to 33 (of www-data)

Comment: One of you should make this into an answer since the problem appears to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help AtomiX84. After resetting the root password i changed uid of jwbosch back to 1000. This was changed to 33 (of www-data)